Название классов
Подскажите, пожалуйста, будет ли  это хорошей практикой давать один класс однотипным элементам в разных секциях, например, .section-title всем заголовкам, а потом стилизовать их как .название секции .section-title. Или лучше каждому тегу давать уникальный класс?

Лично я ничего плохого в этом не вижу. Для section-title у вас будут общая стилизация, а дополнительным классом вы можете изменить заголовок под нужды конкретной секции.

Зависит от того, как вы будете взаимодействовать с этими элементами. Общего правила нет, но обычно правила обращения в DOM-объектам оговариваются перед началом проекта командой.
